# Give namespace to an existing library in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Some library in C++ doesn't use namespace like stl does. Like ncurses, functions available there can be called without namespace. It has `move ()` function that can be accessed globally. And now, I'm taking `ncurses` library in my class file which will have `move` function as it's member function. If i write my class like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

class MyClass {
    public:
        void move (int x, int y) {
            // moving
        }
        void do_something (int x, int y) {
            move (x, y);
            // do something
        }
}
```

I don't know which `move ()` function will be called by `MyClass`. I think the problem will gone if can give `ncurses` library a namespace, so can use (for example) `ncurses::move ()` not just `move ()`. Is it possible to give it namespace? If not, what will you do if you find to something like this (not changing function name of course)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can fully qualify the call, rather than relying on name lookup which basically finds the "nearest" match, like this:

```
::move(x, y);
```

This will look for `move` at the top level, finding the ncurses, no-namespace, version.

For adding an `ncurses` namespace, not really. You could try:

```
namespace ncurses {
#include <ncurses.h>
}
```

but it's really nasty and almost certainly won't work properly. Another way would be to create a wrapper header that manually adds all the functions you are interested in into a namespace, like:

```
// wrapped_ncurses.h
#ifndef WRAPPED_NCURSES_H
#define WRAPPED_NCURSES_H
#include <ncurses.h>
namespace ncurses {
    using ::move;
}
#endif
```

And then of course you can take this as far as you like towards creating a C++ wrapper for the entire library ([or try to find an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/544280/1171191)).

Comment: Is that mean I can't really prevent global functions that defined in library from being accessed globally?

Comment: @BagolDaplun Not with the approach described above. You can if you create a simple wrapper: create a header with a namespace. Put in it function declarations with the same signatures as those you want from ncurses. In the corresponding `.cpp` files, put definitions that just call the ncurses versions, but only `#include <ncurses.h>` here. That way no one else sees the original top-level declarations. Can be fiddly though.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know which `move ()` function will be called by `MyClass`.

The member function, since that's in the narrower scope. Unqualified name lookup starts in the local scope and works outwards until it finds a match. So here it will look in the function's block scope; then move out to the class; then find `MyClass::move` and stop there. It won't consider the global namespace outside the class.

> Is it possible to give it namespace?

You can qualify the name as `::move` to specify the global namespace.